# Étymologie de « d'après »

Tags: prépositions, étymologie

Étrangement, le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%E2%80%99apr%C3%A8s) et le [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/d%27apr%C3%A8s) manquent d'entrées pour cette préposition.

1. Compte tenu de l'existence de « après  », comment et pourquoi 
   « d'après  » a-t-elle  surgi ?
   « d'après  » m'apparaît redondante ; « après  », aurait-elle pu épouser toutes ses acceptions ?
2. Que signifie la préposition « de » élidée,  dans « d'après  » ?

Veuillez m’aider à approfondir la définition. Je constate l’Erreur Étymologique. Mais quelles sont des façons correctes d’interpréter cette acception ?

Comment: J'ai du mal à saisir pourquoi tu perçois une redondance entre ces deux expressions. Je ne leur connais aucune utilisation commune. Il est vrai que dans certains cas, « d'après » peut être traduit en anglais par « _after_ » mais c'est assez exceptionnel (je n'ai qu'un seul cas en tête, « _he was named **after** his grandfather_ »). Après, l'origine de la construction de cette expression est effectivement intéressante.

Comment: Quelle Erreur ?

Answer (score 1):

Je relève juste le 4e sens de [après](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/apr%C3%A8s) qui n'est pas relié à une relation spatiale ou temporelle :

> Indique sur quoi portent certaines actions ou intentions.
>
> > - Au Labo, c’est après Boucherot que j’ai demandé.
> > - Nahoum l'apprit et vint hurler après moi.
> > - Les chiens aboient après le facteur, ils en ont méchamment après lui.
> > - Venez vite ! Les clients s’emportent après le personnel de la réception.

---

Je vais commencer par ta deuxième question qui permet de répondre en partie à la première:

**2)** *"après"* seul indique une personne ou une chose sur laquelle repose l'action, le *"de"* permet de d'exprimer la **référence** qu'on fait à cette personne/chose ayant effectué une action.

• Par exemple :

> D'après ma mère, il ne faut pas parler aux inconnus.

*"Après ma mère"* aurait signifié une relation de ma mère à l'action de parler aux inconnus.

*"D'après ma mère"* fait référence à ma mère donnant un conseil, celui de ne pas parler aux inconnus.

• Exemple du [wiktionaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%E2%80%99apr%C3%A8s) pour le sens de *"Selon ; conformément à."*

> La religiosité, soit au lieu de la réalité l'apparence, remplace donc la religion au Morvan, du moins d’après quelques écrivains.

Ici, *"après quelques écrivains"* aurait fait référence à des écrivains pratiquant la religiosité, alors qu'on veut faire référence à des écrivains écrivant sur la religiosité.

• Et pour le sens de *"En conséquence de."* :

> D’après ces observations, il est possible que notre théorie soit inexacte.

On ne parle pas du fait d'observer (avec *"après"*), mais bien des informations relevées lors de ces observations(*"d'après"*).

**1)** Comme vu dans 2), ce n'est pas une redondance mais une référence à une action effectuée par ce qui suit *"après"* et non une référence à l'action actuelle.

Answer (score 0):

Aucune des deux acceptions courantes de l'expression « d'après » ne peut être remplacée par un simple « après ».

Le [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/apr%C3%A8s) indique bien la première, locution prépositionnelle signifiant « suivant la norme, le modèle de » (en anglais: *according to, from*), par exemple :

> Les Misérables, d'après Victor Hugo. -> *based on a book from Victor Hugo* .

Quand « d'après » est une locution adjectivale servant à indiquer la postériorité, il peut être remplacé par « suivant » mais pas par « après » sans « d' ».

> Le jour d'après = Le jour suivant. -> *The day after*

Quand il s'agit d'une préposition, pas de « d' »:

> Deux jours après leur arrivée -> Two days after their arrival.